# How can we setPost value in Magento2

Tags: magento2, parameter

In **magento1** we are able to set Post value like following

```
$this->getRequest()->setPost('super_attribute', null)
```

So how can we set post in magento2?

Answer (score 2):

You can setpost value in magento 2 like this,
In magento 2 `setPost()` is deprecated and its use `setPostValue()`

If you want to use observer then,

```
public function addOrder(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
    $request = $observer->getRequestModel();

    $orderData = array();
    $request->setPostValue('order', $orderData);
}
```

in normal you can use,

```
 $orderData = array();
$this->getRequest()->setPostValue('order', $orderData);
```

Comment: Do we need to get object of \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request  or anythingelse because i tried with setParams but did not work. I am trying it in observer model

Comment: When i add this... it wont add to cart product so it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I am not Sure but you can also use $_POST 
like `$_POST['super_attribute'] = null;`

Comment: But $_POST we can not use direct global array in magento2 as per the standard.